# How transport to dev team software crash'es from remote clients machines?

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, crash-dumps

I searching people who know some experience with bug tracking on client machines,
if my application works on many client machines who i don't have to it any access.
I have in my application very huge debug logging feature, but in many cases this is
to less to good detect problem of crash without very bigs and unreadable logs, then i searching some other solution for detect this type of problems.

I want to develop some code who good transport me information about software crashes.
On Developer machine i use after crash `Visual Studio JIT Debugger`, but in remote option i can't use it (i think) is any good way to transport information about crash to me in for example `JIT` crash format?

I want this solution for pure `C++` unmanaged project and for managed `C#` separately.

Greetings,
Thanks for good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dondu/writing-minidumps-in-c) about minidumps. It should do what you want (I think).

Comment: Minidumps are cross language, and the snippet on the blog post seems to be written straight from a C/C++ app.

Answer (score 2):

The nice thing about this is that you don't need to write a line of code. Microsoft has already written all the code for you. Have you ever encountered one of those "Report this crash to Microsoft" dialogs? That's sending the crash information that you want.

Wait, you may say, that's going to Microsoft, not me. Indeed, but you can get the information from Microsoft. They will even group the crashes by crash location, and provide nice statistics. You only need to do a few things. One, you need to sign your software so Microsoft knows it's your software. Two, you need to sign up for the [Windows Quality Online Services (WinQual)](https://winqual.microsoft.com/help/default.htm). Three, you need to list which versions of your software you've released.